# Specifying queue name for Laravel notifications

Tags: laravel, notifications, queue, laravel-queue, laravel-notification

I'm building a SAAS and I want each tenant to have their own queue for notifications. I have a notification class that implements `Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue` and I send the notification like this

```php
$user->notify($notification);
```

But I haven't found a way to specify the queue that I want the notification to be pushed to. I know that jobs can be pushed to specific queues with `onQueue`:

```php
ProcessPodcast::dispatch($podcast)->onQueue('tenant1');
```

But is it possible to do something like this for queueable notifications as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your notification should use [the `Illuminate\Bus\Queueable` trait](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Bus/Queueable.php) you can simply set the `$queue` property of the object. There's [a helper function](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Bus/Queueable.php#L95) for it:

```php
$notification->onQueue('tenant1');
$user->notify($notification);
```

Comment: Awesome! That's simple enough. Thanks!